# Is it preferable for someone to ask God To take revenge on a specific person for him rather than doing by himself?

Tags: halal-haram, dua

The reason I’m asking this because, we were oppressed by another 2 Muslim children. Allow me to tell you a little story.

**STORY TIME**

Long ago, when me and my sister we’re Christians, we were small. My she was at age of 9 and me at age of 13 in one of Kuwait's school, and there was 2 Muslim kids that they humiliated us badly for no reason, and I used to know much about them without they to know about me that I know, I used to know there names, and street address and there home, so that I can take revenge on them but, few years later at age of 15, I have become a Muslim and she didn't. But then, I forgot completely there names, street address and how there home look like.

**THE END OF STORY**

At the age of 16, when we came back home in Bucharest, I completely forgot about that incident as if never occured, and the feelings too disappeared as if I never been oppressed. But another years later, my sister brought the subject about our past, and I didn’t believed in what she said and I felt as if she telling the truth. But the, I got extremely angry. My Christian mother advised me not to take revenge on them, because it is huge sin, because God hates those who take revenge. And then, I got even more angry because I got stuck, that I can’t do anything.

And I was wondering if I can ask God To Send an angel and to appear to them in a form of a man, and to announce them by saying: “Your Lord has grounded you severely”, and to ask God also to allow them, only those two to see jinns and devils and where ever they go only they can see, and not even there parents cannot see what they see, and to ask God also to order some jinns and spirits and devils to scare them just like never been scared, and to have also very bad dreams as a severe punishment like never seen or heard before, and To scare them also when they are in bathroom and nothing shall work as a protection and to make them be the biggest failures and losers in the His creation and in there school and to make them be more humiliated more than they did to us and there punishment shall continue for 2 or 3 years or more as long as God wants and after there punishment ends then everything will get back to normal and also to punish them badly just like He punish a evil and stubborn disbeliever in Hereafter. Am I allowed to ask this from God to take revenge on them? “Because”, even now at age of 18 I still feel very angry at them. Can I make tthis dua to God Almighty?

**NOTE:** Can anyone tell me if there is any grammatical mistake out there? And, can you tell me if there is something to edit? Oh and, I’m aching for revenge, I’m only looking to do right things, because I’ve been oppressed badly. And please, tell me if everything I wrote is 100% crystal clear, readable text.

Comment: "Peace be upon you brother"
It is better to forgive them because it's sooth hearts and it is a wise choice. Or you can leave it on Allah for day of judgment. 
Trust me bro it is better to forgive them from heart and go forward. If you forgive them by heart for the sake of Allah, In sha Allah it's sooth your heart and Allah will give you reward for this. 
Jajakallah Khairaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Dear Brother I Will Advice You To Forgive Them, Because Since You Are Now A Muslim Remember That All Muslims Are Brothers

Answer (score 6):

وَجَزَاءُ سَيِّئَةٍ سَيِّئَةٌ مِثْلُهَا ۖ فَمَنْ عَفَا وَأَصْلَحَ فَأَجْرُهُ عَلَى اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّهُ لَا يُحِبُّ الظَّالِمِينَ

Chapter 42 Council, Consultation سورة الشورى - Ash-Shura: Verse 40

## Translation:

The recompense for an injury is an injury equal thereto (in degree): but if a person forgives and makes reconciliation, his reward is due from Allah: for (Allah) loveth not those who do wrong.

I know that you are aching for revenge, but you will be rewarded if you forgive those who has offended you. Instead of praying for their misery, pray for them to be good and to ask forgiveness from their victims.

Comment: Actually, you presented the best way of that, namely forgiving. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score 0):

Like all the people who commented before me, forgive is the way of Islam and aching for revenge is quite common in human beings so keep in mind that karma exists in Islam too. It differentiates between people. Some will live a great life but then pay for what they’ve done in hell. And some, they get their karma while living.
  This is a story my mom found on facebook a few years ago. This girl and her siblings became orphans at a quite young age and their uncle took custody of them. But he was not a nice man to be said per se. He used up the orphans’ money for his own use. Bossed around the kids and etc. One day, their aunt (uncle’s sister) came to visit and saw how poorly the kids were living and she, if i’m not mistaken argued till the children were under her care. After that, karma came after their uncle. I couldn’t really say it specifically as I don’t remember but it included death of his close family members and he got very ill. Financial was bad. He got what he deserved. God is always justice. Remember that :)